# Getting Missing Manifest class or ClassNotFoundException after Android Studio update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-permissions

I have defines custom permissions in its manifest and the Android Gradle plugin typically generates a `Manifest.java` class that includes your custom permissions as String constants. The plugin packages this class with your app, so you can more easily reference those permissions at runtime. but after the android studio update it's not working.

Comment: can you post the error message and screen shot of it?

Answer (score 0):

As per google announcement Generating the manifest class is currently broken in `Android Gradle plugin 3.6.0` and higher. If you build your app with this version of the plugin, and it references the manifest class, you might see a `ClassNotFoundException` exception. To resolve this issue, do one of the following:

- Reference your custom permissions by their fully-qualified name. For example,
  **"com.example.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"**
- Define your own constants, as shown below:

  ```
  public final class CustomPermissions {
    public static final class permission {
      public static final String DEADLY_ACTIVITY="com.example.myapp.permission.DEADLY_ACTIVITY";
    }
  ```